# How does Gunn diode generate oscilations?

Tags: diodes, oscillator

The Gunn diode can produce spontaneous oscillation if biased to the -ve resistance region of operation. How ? What exactly makes it tick ?

Comment: A few seconds with Google will answer this. Question should be closed.

Comment: @LeonHeller Not as much as an experienced professional it won't.

Comment: It's the -ve resistance. A +ve resistance makes oscillations decay by absorbing power. A -ve one makes them grow by supplying power. For how the Gunn structure makes it behave as a -ve resistor, see AJ below, or google.

Comment: The negative resistance region is a bit of a misnomer giving the impression its actually negative resistance (V/I = -R), which doesn't exist.  Its simply a region where dV/dI has a negative slope (= -dR). (see also beam tetrode valve).  This dynamic negative resistance effectively removes the resistance from an LC(R) circuit causing it to oscillate continuously rather than be damped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible because Gunn diodes are usually made of compound semiconductors (usually N type) therefore there are two energetic valleys of different value. See the picture below. What it means is  that if you add strong electric field, electrons will climb up the valley and have higher effective mass so they won't be as fast as the ones in the lower energetic valley. Electrons will start to pile up there at the higher valley forming a domain of electric field which will travel across the structure bringing diode into negative resistance region. As this domain reaches the end of a structure, it dissolves and new domains can be formed.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Now can you explain how Quantum tunelling ties in here, if at all ? From my understanding, Gunn diodes are made as having (n+ n n+) structures. Which causes a Electric field barrier at the middle; which is overcome using tunelling ?

Also are the clump of electrons, supposed to be in a Energy band other than VB and CB ?

Comment: Gunn diodes have highly doped regions, yes, but they don't serve the purpose of forming a barrier, they are used to form low resistance connection point. I will try to add energy diagram to further explain how does it look like

Comment: Thanks a bunch for the energy band diagram. Bear with me here, the electrons clump together in higher valley by means of tunneling, correct ?

Comment: As I understand no. Well, this energy band diagram x axis shows electron momentum, not coordinate. These are different. Usually this one is used to tell whether semiconductor is direct or indirect. As you can clearly see, GaAs is direct semiconductor therefore suitable for laser diodes and LEDs. When sufficient voltage is applied current decreases therefore negative resistance therefore oscillation can occur